# Add the ImageView in specific row of listView in android

Tags: android, listview, imageview, row

This is my adapter class, in which i have a child view as cleared in my class, now i need to add an image on some specific row in this same adapter class, is there any way to add an image on some specific row, suppose at 10th row of list within same adapter class?

```
 public class abc extends BaseAdapter {
  private static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;
  private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;
  ArrayList<ListData> myList = new ArrayList<ListData>();
  ArrayList<rowData> details = new ArrayList<rowData>();
  ArrayList<Integer> imagePosition = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  LayoutInflater inflater;
  Context context;  

public abc(Context context, ArrayList<ListData> myList)
{ 
    this.myList = myList; 
    this.context = context; 
    setImageViewPosition(10);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context); 
// only context can also be used 
} 
@Override public int getCount() { 
    return myList == null ? 0 : myList.size(); 
    } 
@Override public ListData getItem(int position) {
    return myList.get(position);
    }  
@Override public long getItemId(int position) { 
    return this.myList.get(position).getViewType();
    }  
@Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 
    MyViewHolder mViewHolder;


        int type = getItemViewType(position);

   if (convertView == null) {
       mViewHolder = new MyViewHolder();
           switch (type) {
               case TYPE_ITEM:
                   convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.beacon_room_list_item1, null);
                   break;
               case 1:
                   convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.beacon_item_0_to_15, null);
                   break;
               case 2:
                   convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.beacon_item_0_to_30, null);
                   break;
               case 3:
                   convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.beacon_item_0_to_45, null);
                   break;
               case 4:
                   convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.beacon_item_0_to_60, null);
                   break;
               case 5:
                   convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.beacon_item_15_to_30, null);
                   break;
               case 6:
                   convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.beacon_item_15_to_45, null);
                   break;
               case 7:
                   convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.beacon_item_15_to_60, null);
                   break;
               case 8:
                   convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.beacon_item_30_to_45, null);
                   break;
               case 9:
                   convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.beacon_item_30_to_60, null);
                   break;
               case 10:
                   convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.beacon_item_45_to_60, null);
                   break;
           }
       convertView.setTag(mViewHolder);
           } else {
               mViewHolder = (MyViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
           }

   switch (type) {
   case TYPE_ITEM:
        mViewHolder.startDate = detail(convertView, R.id.datetitle, myList.get(position).getTitle());
       break;
   case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
   case 2:
   case 3:
   case 4:
   case 5:
   case 6:
   case 7:
   case 8:
   case 9:
   case 10:
   case 11:
       mViewHolder.startDate = detail(convertView, R.id.datetitle, myList.get(position).getTitle());
       mViewHolder.organiser = detail(convertView, R.id.organiser, myList.get(position).organiser);
       break;
   }
   for(Integer i : imagePosition)
   {
      if(i == position)
      {
          ImageView imgView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.meetingline);
          mViewHolder.ivIcon =imgView;
          notifyDataSetChanged();
      }
   }
    return convertView; 
    }

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 12;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    return this.myList.get(position).getViewType();

    /*
    if(this.myList.get(position).getorganiser().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
    {
        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }
    else
    {
        return TYPE_SEPARATOR;
    }*/
}


// or you can try better way
private TextView detail(View v, int resId, String text) {
    TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(resId);

    if(tv != null )
        tv.setText(text); 

    return tv;
    }  
private ImageView details(View v, int resId, int icon) {
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) v.findViewById(resId);
    iv.setImageResource(icon);
    return iv;
    } 
private class MyViewHolder {
    TextView startDate,calendar,organiser; 
//  View v = findViewById(R.id.our_view); 

    // Get params:

    ImageView ivIcon;
    } 

public void setImageViewPosition(int position)
{
   imagePosition.add(position);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is add the imageview to the row xml file and make it invisible like this:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone" />
```

and then when you want that ImageView to be shown, you can do it in the Base Adapter class like this:

```
ImageView imgView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.myImageView);
imgView .setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: dude where is the position of row?

Comment: @steve what do you mean "where is the position of row" ?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a conditional to your getView() method, wherein you set or construct an ImageView if the position is 10.  You just need to make sure to take it into account that that position is filled when constructing views for positions after the image view.

```
private int imageViewPosition = 10;

@Override
public View getView(final int pos, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    if (pos == imageViewPosition) {
        // you should construct and return your image view
    }

    int position = pos;
    if (pos > imageViewPosition) {
        position = pos - 1;
    }

    // construct stuff for position
}
```

You will also need to change any other adapter methods to account for (a) the extra view and (b) the shift in positions after that extra view, such as getItem(), getCount(), etc...

Your ListView will look something like this:

```
view 1: stuff for position 1
view 2: stuff for position 2
...
view 9: stuff for position 9
view 10: your inserted imageview 
view 11: stuff for position 10
```

Hope this helps :)